# Vertical Scroll, ListView with WinJS

Tags: html, css, windows-8, winjs

How can I make a ListView scrolling vertically with HTML/JS in an Windows8 application using WinJS?

I've developed an Windows 8 app with XAML/C# and in the application I used a ListView to get a list with vertical scrolling behavior.

I'm now trying to create the same app with HTML/JS but failing to create a list with ListView that scrolls vertically. It automatically puts the ListItems on a horizontal line and scrolling horizontally.

I thought that GridView can be used for "lists" with horizontal scrolling and ListView for vertical scrolling.

I've also tried to wrap the ListView within a div that scrolls vertically on overflow by using this:

```
<div style="overflow-y:scroll;">
    // ListView
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In XAML, you use different controls - GridView for a horizontal list of items that fill by column and wrap when they run out of vertical space and ListView for a vertical list of items that fills by column and does not wrap.

In HTML, you use a ListView for both cases. To switch between the same two behaviors, you set the ListView's `layout` property. Set it to `new WinJS.UI.GridLayout()` for the equivalent of a XAML GridView and to `new WinJS.UI.ListLayout()` for the equivalent of a XAML ListView.

You can do this in JavaScript with something like...

```
    if (Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.value == Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationViewState.snapped) {
        demosListView.layout = new WinJS.UI.ListLayout();
    }
    else {
        demosListView.layout = new WinJS.UI.GridLayout();
    }
```

Or you can set this declaratively in the HTML using the data-win-options attribute of the ListView control div.
Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, `data-win-options="{layout: {type: WinJS.UI.ListLayout}}"` did the work!